# Android - GridView and image performance issue

Tags: android, performance, gridview

I have a `GridView` which load about 15 images, not so much, but when I test it the scroll is really slow, I cannot figured out why.

I get all the images from an `array.xml` file.

array.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="chuck_ids">
        <item>@drawable/chuck_1</item>
        <item>@drawable/chuck_2</item>
        <item>@drawable/chuck_3</item>
        <item>@drawable/chuck_4</item>
        <item>@drawable/chuck_5</item>
        <item>@drawable/chuck_6</item>
        <item>@drawable/chuck_7</item>
        <item>@drawable/chuck_8</item>
        <item>@drawable/chuck_9</item>
        <item>@drawable/chuck_10</item>
        <item>@drawable/chuck_11</item>
        <item>@drawable/chuck_12</item>
        <item>@drawable/chuck_13</item>
        <item>@drawable/chuck_14</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

and this is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.InflateException;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;

import com.italiandevteam.chuck.adapter.GridViewAdapter;
import com.italiandevteam.chuck.model.ImageItem;

public class GalleriaPersonaggio extends Fragment{

    Integer personaggio = null;


    public GalleriaPersonaggio( int personaggio ){

        this.personaggio = personaggio;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        int id = getIdPersonaggio();

        View rootView = null;

        try {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_grid, container, false);
            } 
        catch (InflateException e) {
        }

        final GridView gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        GridViewAdapter customGridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.gallery_row, getData(personaggio));
        gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
//              HashMap<String, Object> hm = gridView.getAdapter().getPosition(position);
//
//                 String imgPath = (String) hm.get("flag"); //get downloaded image path
//              Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), MostraImmagine.class); //start new Intent to another Activity.
//              i.putExtra("ClickedImagePath", imgPath ); //put image link in intent.
//              startActivity(i);
            }

    });

        return rootView;
    }

    public int getIdPersonaggio(){
        return this.personaggio;
    }

    private ArrayList getData(int personaggio) {
        final ArrayList imageItems = new ArrayList();
        // retrieve String drawable array
        TypedArray imgs = null;

        switch( personaggio )
        {        
            case 1:{
                imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.chuck_ids);
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.sarah_ids);
                break;
            }
            case 3:{
                //To do
                break;
            }
            case 4:{
                //To do
                break;
            }
            case 5:{
                //To do
                break;
            }
            case 6:{
                //To do
                break;
            }
            case 7:{
                //To do
                break;
            }
            case 8:{
                //To do
                break;
            }
            default:{
                imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.chuck_ids);
            }

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length(); i++) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));
            imageItems.add(new ImageItem(bitmap, "Image#" + i));
        }

        return imageItems;

    }
}
```

GridViewAdapter.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.italiandevteam.chuck.R;
import com.italiandevteam.chuck.model.ImageItem;


public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ImageItem> {
    private Context context;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private ArrayList<ImageItem> data = new ArrayList<ImageItem>();

    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
                    ArrayList<ImageItem> data) {
            super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
            this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
            this.context = context;
            this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            ViewHolder holder = null;

            if (row == null) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
                    row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.imageTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);
                    holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);
                    row.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
            }

            ImageItem item = data.get(position);
            holder.imageTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
            holder.image.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
            return row;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
            TextView imageTitle;
            ImageView image;
    }
}
```

ImageItem.java

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;


public class ImageItem {
    private Bitmap image;
    private String title;

    public ImageItem(Bitmap image, String title) {
        super();
        this.image = image;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Bitmap getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Bitmap image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Basically I load the `drawable` resource based on the `array ID` in the switch in the java file.
How can I improve the scrolling?

Comment: Have a read through this: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html Particularly the part about loading images in a `GridView`

Comment: Show your `GridViewAdapter`, especially its `getView()`.

Comment: How large are the bitmaps you pre-load? If they are "large", scaling them down to display size in `setImageBitmap()` will block the UI thread long enough for the scrolling experience to be affected.

Comment: My images are quite big honestly, about 480x600 should I create two version? One for the thumbs and one for the full image view?

Answer (score 0):

Please try [Universal Image Downloader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) to load images either from server or SD card. It works like charm!!

Comment: This is unlikely to be really helpful as the OP is using images from resources.

Comment: you can also download image from resources using this library.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should create thumbs and also cache the memory. It will definitely solve your problem.

This is the link for caching implementation in android.

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html